# Is it possible to transfer files from desktop application to the mobile application via Bluetooth/WiFi, built using Electron?

Tags: android, bluetooth, electron, desktop-application

I am trying to develop an app using Electron that have to share the files between android and desktop using Bluetooth/WiFi technology. I surfed internet as how much as I can, but I didn't get any proper solution.

Still I am confused whether it is possible or not. Can anybody clarify my doubt.

If it is possible, share me a sample of the code or share me the link where I can get what I'm looking for.

Thanks 
Bala